# OpenGL glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) vs glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0)

Tags: opengl, c++

I would like to ask which one of these is better to use after I finished my texture rendering.

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0)
```

Is there any difference performance-wise?

Answer (score 11):

### These are two fundamentally different things.

#### glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)

- Disables 2D textures for the active Texture Unit in the ***fixed-function*** OpenGL pipeline.
- In programmable OpenGL (GLSL or the older ARB VP/FP assembly languages), enabling or disabling `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is meaningless.

#### glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D,0)

- Binds the ***"default"*** texture to the active Texture Image Unit.
- For all intents and purposes, there is *always* a texture bound to a Texture Image Unit; **0** is just a special-case with an *initially* incomplete set of states, thus complicating ***validation*** (*see below*).

There is a little bit of validation overhead associated with binding any OpenGL resource (GLSL programs and FBOs tend to have the most complicated validation). In general, changing an object binding tends to be more expensive than changing one or two states associated with a bound object.

Therefore, unnecessarily changing the bound texture is inadvisable.

If your intention by binding **0** was simply to *"disable"* a texture, you would be better off setting a ***uniform*** value to communicate this intent to a shader. Uniforms are extremely cheap to set (assuming you do not do something stupid like query their location everytime you set them). Changing a uniform is orders of magnitude quicker than binding a different texture or even worse a different GLSL program.

---

#### If you are using fixed-function OpenGL:

- Disabling `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is a better way of approaching this problem.
- Changing bound objects should be done as little as possible.

#### If you are using programmable OpenGL:

- Neither of these things make much sense.
- Work your desired behavior into your shaders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using fixed-function OpenGL and Im trying to create simple library with functions for rendering 2D textures.

Comment: I am using programmable OpenGL (shaders) with multi-texturing: I was able to disable single textures by calling glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2) and glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0), before calling the shader: